# Single use access token?

Tags: oauth-2.0, identityserver4

To my understanding, it can create a short live access token.   But does it have a single use access token that is similar to what the Authorization code is?

What is the best approach in doing it?   I have thought about using refresh token, but that is still short live, not single(one-time use).

OR can it do it this way:

App1 needs to get an access token from IS4 to call App2, but that token can be used once only.   Can the IS4 keep something in the state and App2 needs to call the introspection endpoint of IS4 (rather than local validation of the JWT) and the IS4 checks its state and allow it once?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure IdentityServer to put a unique value (the `jti` claim) into an access token. That's a client setting.

This can be used to maintain a replay cache at the API to reject token that are used more than once. The token lifetime helps to trim the cache.